Is there a way to include column index name with Pandas dataframe to CSV?
Is there a way to include the column (not rows!) index name in the output when calling Pandas' dataframe.to_csv() method? For example:
import pandas as pd

iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
pivot_iris = iris.pivot_table(index='species', columns='sepal_length', values='sepal_width')

print(pivot_iris.columns)
print(pivot_iris)

pivot_iris.to_csv('pivot_iris.csv', index=True, header=True)

After calling pivot, the column index name is set to sepal_length as you can see in the prints
Index([4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5.0, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6,
       5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.0,
       7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.6, 7.7, 7.9],
      dtype='float64', name='sepal_length')

and
sepal_length  4.3       4.4  4.5    4.6  4.7  ...  7.3  7.4  7.6   7.7  7.9
species                                       ...                          
setosa        3.0  3.033333  2.3  3.325  3.2  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
versicolor    NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
virginica     NaN       NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN  ...  2.9  2.8  3.0  3.05  3.8

[3 rows x 35 columns]

Unfortunately the output file produced with to_csv() is missing the label in front of the column names:
species,4.30,4.40,4.50,4.60,4.70,4.80,4.90,5.00,5.10,5.20,5.30,5.40,5.50,5.60,5.70,5.80,5.90,6.00,6.10,6.20,6.30,6.40,6.50,6.60,6.70,6.80,6.90,7.00,7.10,7.20,7.30,7.40,7.60,7.70,7.90
setosa,3.00,3.03,2.30,3.33,3.20,3.18,3.20,3.36,3.60,3.67,3.70,3.66,3.85,,4.10,4.00,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
versicolor,,,,,,,2.40,2.15,2.50,2.70,,3.00,2.44,2.82,2.82,2.67,3.10,2.80,2.88,2.55,2.70,3.05,2.80,2.95,3.07,2.80,3.10,3.20,,,,,,,
virginica,,,,,,,2.50,,,,,,,2.80,2.50,2.73,3.00,2.60,2.80,3.10,2.93,2.92,3.05,,3.04,3.10,3.13,,3.00,3.27,2.90,2.80,3.00,3.05,3.80

is there a way to include it?

What would be the expected CSV output?

You can't really include the index names in a CSV.
What you could do is to create a MultiIndex:
pivot_iris = (pd.concat({'sepal_length':
                         iris.pivot_table(index='species', columns='sepal_length', values='sepal_width')},
                        axis=1)
                  .rename_axis(columns=(None, 'species')).reset_index()
             )

pivot_iris.to_csv('pivot_iris.csv', index=False)

Output:
species,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length,sepal_length
,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8,4.9,5.0,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,6.0,6.1,6.2,6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9,7.0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.6,7.7,7.9
setosa,3.0,3.03,2.3,3.32,3.2,3.18,3.2,3.36,3.6,3.67,3.7,3.66,3.85,,4.1,4.0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
versicolor,,,,,,,2.4,2.15,2.5,2.7,,3.0,2.44,2.82,2.82,2.67,3.1,2.8,2.88,2.55,2.7,3.05,2.8,2.95,3.07,2.8,3.1,3.2,,,,,,,
virginica,,,,,,,2.5,,,,,,,2.8,2.5,2.73,3.0,2.6,2.8,3.1,2.93,2.92,3.05,,3.04,3.1,3.13,,3.0,3.27,2.9,2.8,3.0,3.05,3.8


Yes that was my workaround idea too, i just thought there might be a more straight forward solution, though it seems this is the way to go then.
